# Issue in Vercel Production. LookupError Resource not Found

Tags: python, flask, nltk, spacy

``           **I am facing this error in production, i didn't face it locally. **

```
[ERROR] 2023-08-07T16:26:11.466Z    fb1bc7be-4061-455a-97b5-bb15babb27e5
```

Exception on      /analyze_language [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/var/task/flask/app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app

```
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
```

File "/var/task/flask/app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request

```
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
```

File "/var/task/flask_cors/extension.py", line 176, in wrapped_function

```
return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
```

File "/var/task/flask/app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request

```
rv = self.dispatch_request()
```

File "/var/task/flask/app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request

```
return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
```

File "./api/index.py", line 96, in analyze_language

```
tenses_and_persons_detected = detect_tenses_and_persons(input_paragraph)
```

File "./api/index.py", line 49, in detect_tenses_and_persons

```
tokens = word_tokenize(paragraph)
```

File "/var/task/nltk/tokenize/**init**.py", line 129, in word_tokenize

```
sentences = [text] if preserve_line else sent_tokenize(text, language)
```

File "/var/task/nltk/tokenize/**init**.py", line 106, in sent_tokenize

```
  tokenizer = load(f"tokenizers/punkt/{language}.pickle")
```

File "/var/task/nltk/data.py", line 750, in load

```
opened_resource = _open(resource_url)
```

File "/var/task/nltk/data.py", line 876, in _open

```
return find(path_, path + [""]).open()
```

File "/var/task/nltk/data.py", line 583, in find

```
raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
```

LookupError:

Resource [93mpunkt[0m not found.

Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

[31m>>> import nltk

> > > nltk.download('punkt')

Attempted to load [93mtokenizers/punkt/PY3/english.pickle[0m

Searched in:

```
- '/home/sbx_user1051/nltk_data'

- '/var/lang/nltk_data'

- '/var/lang/share/nltk_data'

- '/var/lang/lib/nltk_data'

- '/usr/share/nltk_data'

- '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'

- '/usr/lib/nltk_data'

- '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'

if __name__ == "__main__":

    nltk.download('punkt')

    nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')

    nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

    app.run(debug=True)
```

`

Comment: @doneforaiur did that. How's that going to help me ?